# Suppress deprecation warnings from Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I am running a standard VQE from the example shown in here https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html, however I keep getting this output constantly (as many times the vqe runs which is a lot).

```
DeprecationWarning: The Python built-in `round` is deprecated for complex scalars, 
and will raise a `TypeError` in a future release. Use `np.round` or `scalar.round` 
instead.
```

is there any way to suppress this without suppressing the entire python terminal as I need the output for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following before running the VQE to suppress the deprecation warning

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
# run VQE here
```

That turns **all** the deprecation warnings off, if you want to turn them on again you can add

```
warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=DeprecationWarning)
```

I don't think there is a way to turn off just Qiskit's deprecation warnings.

Comment: Just what im looking for, thanks!

Comment: Great! Could you accept the answer so others see it has been addressed?

Answer (score 1):

@Cryoris answer is perfectly valid, but a more "Pythonic" way of doing this is with the help of the `with` keyword:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
    # Run VQE here, respect the identation.
# /!\ At this level of identation, warnings are no longer ignored.
# No need to think to call another method afterwards.
```

The issue with this code being that you ignore **all** the deprecation warnings. If you want to only ignore the one that bother you, add a filter:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", 
                          category=DeprecationWarning, 
                          message=(
                                 "The Python built-in round is deprecated for complex "
                                 "scalars, and will raise a TypeError in a future release. "
                                 "Use np.round or scalar.round instead."
                             ) 
                         ) 
    # Run VQE here, respect the identation.
# /!\ At this level of identation, warnings are no longer ignored.
# No need to think to call another method afterwards.
```

This answer has been constructed from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/4810787) and the [`warnings` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings).

I tested with

```
import warnings
def f():
    warnings.warn("The Python built-in round is deprecated for complex scalars, and will raise a TypeError in a future release. Use np.round or scalar.round instead.", DeprecationWarning)
    
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 
                          category=DeprecationWarning, 
                          message=(
                                 "The Python built-in round is deprecated for complex "
                                 "scalars, and will raise a TypeError in a future release. "
                                 "Use np.round or scalar.round instead."
                             ) 
                         ) 
    print("In 'with' block:")
    f()
    print("Done")
print("Out of 'with' block:")
f()
print("Done")
```

that prints

```
In 'with' block:
Done
Out of 'with' block:
-c:2: DeprecationWarning: The Python built-in round is deprecated for complex scalars, and will raise a TypeError in a future release. Use np.round or scalar.round instead.
Done
```

in my IPython session. You can check that the warning has been filtered within the `with` block and not filtered outside of it.