# Suppress Warnings

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I wish to know how to suppress the following warning obtained on qiskit when I try to add two different types of noise to a qubit

```
WARNING: quantum error already exists for instruction "u2" on qubits [0] , appending additional error.
```

I know that some warnings can be suppressed with

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
```

but I do not know what category my warning is contained in. I would also like to know if I can access somewhere all the different warning categories. Additionally trying

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

to suppress all warnings does not help.

Comment: do you mind adding a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit's `NoiseModel` class processes warnings through a logger from the `logging` package, not through the `warnings` package, so suppressing warnings as in other answers won't help.

However, each method in `NoiseModel`  provides a `warnings` parameter; it defaults to `True` but you can set it to `False` to prevent the warnings from being logged.

Example: `myNoiseModel.add_quantum_error(..., warnings=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I **don't know** if this help at all but in term of warning categories, I used `?? warnings` and found a few other types:

```
category=PendingDeprecationWarning
category=ImportWarning
category=ResourceWarning
```

---

I also see a question [related to warning to Qiskit here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13181/suppress-deprecation-warnings-from-qiskit). It is not the same as what you are asking but hopefully it will help somehow.

---

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a category to silence all of the warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I tried this and nothing changes. I have updated the question to include this. Have you any other suggestions?